# Why do I need to move the mouse in order to scroll after I switch windows with alt-tab?

Tags: gnome, mouse, 21.10, wayland

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 with the default Gnome 40 based desktop environment and Wayland display server, and I've noticed that, if I switch windows with Alt-Tab, I have to move the mouse cursor before I can scroll the window with the scroll wheel. This problem occurs when I have to hit Alt-Tab more than once to switch to the window in question.

So for example, let's say I have Chrome, Gnome Terminal and Visual Studio Code open, with the focus set to Visual Studio Code. I hit Alt-Tab twice to switch to Chrome. At this point the mouse's scroll wheel doesn't do anything. However, if I move the mouse cursor slightly, I can use the scroll wheel like normal. It's almost as if the window I've alt-tabbed to doesn't really have focus until I move the mouse.

I'm not even sure how to diagnose what's wrong here much less fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was Wayland. I switched from Ubuntu to Ubuntu on XOrg, and the problem stopped.